# Expanding jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery

Lets say you have 5 "accordions" (i.e. 5 expandible/collapsible sections). Is it possible to preset one of these sections to be expanded when the page is loaded?

Comment: Shouldn't there be an option to set which one should be opened by default?

Comment: Without knowing which accordion you are using, it is going to be quite hard to give advice on this matter. But anyway: write in your javascript when the document is ready to select the first accordion item and then call the slideDown function that will be in the accordion javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needs collapsible: true.

Code examples
Initialize a accordion with the active option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
```

Get or set the active option, after init.
//getter

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```

//setter

```
  $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

I hope that helps. You may check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

`$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });`

if you don't specify an option explicitly it'll default to first child
 [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active) is a demonstration maybe it'll help

Answer (score 1):

yes there is active property to determine the default expanded section

you can see it here [active](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active)